# Use numeric features for contextual bandit with vowpal wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I currently try to get familiar with contextual bandits using vowpal wabbit, but I have some problems to use numerical features.
Basically my bandit should make a decision between two actions (action 1 = send data, action 2 = idle) based on two numerical features (estimated data rate and age of information). This is my simple code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw

train_data = [{'action': 2, 'cost': 0.1, 'probability': 0.5, 'feature1': 3, 'feature2': 10},
              {'action': 1, 'cost': 9.99, 'probability': 0.6, 'feature1': 3, 'feature2': 10},
              {'action': 1, 'cost': 0.1, 'probability': 0.2, 'feature1': 29, 'feature2': 90},
              {'action': 2, 'cost': 9.99, 'probability': 0.3, 'feature1': 29, 'feature2': 90}]
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
train_df['index'] = range(1, len(train_df) + 1)
train_df = train_df.set_index("index")

test_data = [{'feature1': 29, 'feature2': 90},
             {'feature1': 3, 'feature2': 10}]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
test_df['index'] = range(1, len(test_df) + 1)
test_df = test_df.set_index("index")

vw = pyvw.vw("--cb 2")

for i in train_df.index:
    action = int(train_df.loc[i, "action"])
    cost = train_df.loc[i, "cost"]
    probability = train_df.loc[i, "probability"]
    feature1 = train_df.loc[i, "feature1"]
    feature2 = train_df.loc[i, "feature2"]

    # Construct the example in the required vw format.
    learn_example = str(action) + ":" + str(cost) + ":" + str(probability) + " | rate:" + str(feature1) + " aoi:" + str(feature2)

    vw.learn(learn_example)

for j in test_df.index:
    feature1 = test_df.loc[j, "feature1"]
    feature2 = test_df.loc[j, "feature2"]

    #test_example = "| " + str(feature1) + " " + str(feature2)
    test_example = "| rate:" + str(feature1) + " aoi:" + str(feature2)

    choice = vw.predict(test_example)
    print(j, choice)
```

The output is:

```
1 1
2 1
```

Normally I would expect that the output is action 1 for the first prediction and action two for the second prediction following the cost structure of my training data. When I change the features values to characters (e.g. "a" for high datarate, "b" for low data rate, like in the official tutorial -> [VW Tutorial](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/contextual_bandits.html)) and adapt the training/testing string, I get the right predictions, so I think the issue is a wrong implementation of the feature:value pairs.

Does anybody know the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising this issue.

In VW, when you use features with numeric values (name:value) the hash is calculated from namespace and feature name. So no matter what numeric value is used VW has only one weight in the model for that feature.

Instead, if you were to use categorical values for your features, (i.e. `rate=low`, `rate=high`) each categorical value gets a weight in the model.

Because when using numerical values there is only one weight for each feature, VW has less degrees of freedom than in the categorical case to map between features and the right action and so it needs more data. In fact, if you were to copy your training dataset 75 times and train with a total of 300 examples then your predictions will be correct. Alternatively, using categorical features your original set of 4 examples is enough for VW to correctly predict your actions. This is how you could format it:

```
2:0.1:0.5 | rate=3 aoi=10
1:9.99:0.6 | rate=3 aoi=10
1:0.1:0.2 | rate=29 aoi=90
2:9.99:0.3 | rate=29 aoi=90
| rate=29 aoi=90
| rate=3 aoi=10
```

**Note:** In the VW text format `=` is not actually a special character like `:` is. The `=` is just part of the feature name and makes it easier for the human reader to identity it as a categorical feature with that name. If there was a feature `rate` that has two possible values `low` or `high`, this could be passed as `rate=low` or `rate=high`. Replacing `=` with something else would change the hash but the learning would not change as they are still interpreted distinct features. So you could also use `rate-high`, `rate_high`, etc.